# Custom Push Notifications Salesforce 1

Tags: salesforce1-app

There's a way to send a custom push notification to Salesforce 1 app, I mean, I would like to send a push notification across a trigger or class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce1 does support push notifications but for specific cases. For example, you would receive push notifications if

- You received an approval request
- Someone mentioned you

There are also in-app notifications which are supported. Both push notifications and in-app notification support in Salesforce1 is explained [here](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_mobile_salesforce1_setup_notifications.htm).

Having said that, I believe you are referring to the push notifications which appear on [Salesforce Console](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_console/Content/sforce_api_console_methods_push_notifications.htm) - these are not available in Salesforce1.